# Unable to compile spring boot project with java and scala using maven

Tags: java, scala, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to set up application using java,scala and spring boot. I have set up pom.xml. The code is running fine in intellij and I am able to run application successfully. But when i use mvn clean install , my project is not compiling.Its giving error as cannot find symbol for the scala class.
I have followed ([this blog](http://francoisbotha.io/2018/05/16/integrating-scala-into-a-spring-boot-project/))

I am attaching below dependency and plugin section of pom.xml

I have tried various solutions and tried to move the order of the execution of spring boot build plugin, but un-successful

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Sample project with spring boot , java ,scala</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.version>2.12.0</scala.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-scala</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile-scala</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                    </args>
                    <jvmArgs>
                        <jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
                    </jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Try using a newer version for `scala-maven-plugin`

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out . The compile goal for the source should be associated with phase -> process-resources and testCompile goal should be associated with phase -> process-test-resources. Below is the snippet

```
        <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-scala</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile-scala</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```